# Return all months instead of just 4

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data from a database, but its only for 4 months out of this year. I would like it to return all 12 months. Im using Sql Server Management Studio 2010. Here is the sql code

```
SELECT  Month   = datename(month,dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0)), Count   (TestName) 
FROM VExecutionGlobalHistory
 Where Tester <> 'dit2988'       
group by
dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0), year(dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0))
order by
dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0), year(dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0))
```

This Returns

```
|April|92  |
|May  |79  |
|June |164 |
|July |162 |
```

I would like to also add some hardcoded data to the return and have July as the most recent, so i would have something like this.

```
|August   |number|
|September|number|
|October  |number|
|November |number|   
|December |number|
|January  |number|
|February |number|
|March    |number|
|April    |92    |
|May      |79    |
|June     |164   |
|July     |162   |
```

where all the "numbers" are ones that arent pulling from the database, just something i want to put

suggestions?

Comment: Your query isn't returning data for those other months because there is no data in `VExecutionGlobalHistory` for those months (excpet possibly for `Tester <> 'dit2988'`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a tally from the initial date to the final date you want, and do a left join with your data by month number and year:

```
DECLARE @start_date DATETIME, @end_date DATETIME;

SELECT @start_date = CAST('2010-08-01' AS DATETIME),
  @end_date = CAST('2011-07-01' AS DATETIME);

WITH MonthTally(initial_date,month_name, month_number, year_number)  AS
(
  SELECT @start_date initial_date, datename(month,@start_date) month_name, month(@start_date) month_number, year(@start_date) year_number
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(month,1,initial_date), datename(month, DATEADD(month,1,initial_date)), month(DATEADD(month,1,initial_date)), year(DATEADD(month,1,initial_date))
  FROM MonthTally
  WHERE initial_date < @end_date
)
SELECT month_name, Count(TestName) 
FROM MonthTally MT
    LEFT JOIN VExecutionGlobalHistory V ON MT.year_number=YEAR(V.StartTime) AND MT.month_number=MONTH(V.StartTime) AND Tester <> 'dit2988'       
group by
  month_name, year_number, month_number
order by
  year_number, month_number
```

Check the functional example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9bd52/3).

Comment: This doesnt return any data, am i missing something?

Comment: Did you tried changing the values of `@start_date` and `@end_date`to the time frame do you want to search? If so, then, instead of your select, try `SELECT * FROM MonthTally` to check which months are generated by the CTE. Also you can post an example of the data stored on VExecutionGlobalHistory, and I'll post the query in SQLFiddle, based on your example.

Comment: I reviewed the code, and removed some unnecessary fields in the group by and order by clauses.

Comment: Be careful with the `@start_date` and `@end_date` values. The year and month are the important values. The dates are written in ODBC canonical format. If CAST doesn't work, you can try instead `CONVERT(datetime, '2010-08-01 00:00:00.000', 120)`

Comment: 2 Row Example of VExecutionGlobalHisotry

ID|Tester |Environment|StartTime |EndTime   |TestName  |
4 |dit2988|ito5       |2013-07-20|2013-07-20|Hold Order|
5 |dit2989|ito4       |2013-06-20|2013-06-20|Account   |

Comment: Ok, I made a correction, and changed the condition from the WHERE to the LEFT JOIN. Watch the example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9bd52/3